# Is my implementation of a Firebase Transaction correct?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I am using a transaction to update a float value in my Firebase database (see below). It works fine, except for this one time when the value didn't update. Everything else worked perfectly (you will see that there is also an object update in the `onComplete`). On a side note; this update to a different child in the database showed that `Input` was the correct value.

I have not been able to recreate this, nor can I find anything in the logs related to this particular transaction.

My question is, does this implementation of a Firebase transaction look error prone. IOW, have I implemented it incorrectly?

```
    private void onInboundTransactionConfirm(DatabaseReference piclCount) {
            piclCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                    float P = mutableData.getValue(Float.class);

                        // Set value and report transaction success
                        mutableData.setValue(P + Input);

                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                       DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String transKey = transactionRef.child(recipientId).push().getKey();

                    TransactionRecord inbound = new TransactionRecord("Transfer", Input, userDirectCode, UserName);
transactionRef.child(recipientId).child(transKey).setValue(inbound);                 
                    // TransactionRecord completed
                    Log.d(TAG, "postInboundTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                }
            });
        }
```

**EDIT 1:**
The following warning is attached to this line: `float P = mutableData.getValue(Float.class);`:

`Unboxing of 'mutableData.getValue(Float.class)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'`

**EDIT 2**:
I could do this:

```
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                float P = mutableData.getValue(Float.class);

                if (Input != 0) {
                    // Set value and report transaction success
                    mutableData.setValue(P + Input);
                }

                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }
```

But my concern is that if the updated value does not get set (ie for some reason `Input` is equal to `0`), would the transaction not then see the return of the non-updated value to the database as being what the user wants it to be set to, therefore not changing the value and ending successfully?

Comment: Were you offline when you run that transaction?

Comment: @AlexMamo in theory, no. However, would this behaviour be explained by a  momentary drop?

Comment: Yes it can. Since a transaction requires access to the current value of a field to determine the new value of a field, there is no way to run transactions while you're not connected to the database server. Can you please confirm that this is the issue?

Comment: I would have no way of confirming as, if it happened at all, it would have been for the briefest moment. This happened in the middle of testing and other internet dependent processes where not interrupted. For instance, the database update in the `onComplete` ran fine.

Comment: Is there a way of handling no change to a database value in a transaction? IOW, forcing it to retry instead of it 'thinking' that it has been successful?

Comment: This is happen automatically. Please see [save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) and [write data offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data_offline).

Comment: I have read those docs, but my concern is highlighted in EDIT 2 in my question.